# How long to wait until the contributors will make a PR

Tags: contributor, project-management, github, etiquette

I have some #hacktoberfest issues in [my project](https://github.com/sm-react/storybook-addon-material-ui/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20label%3Ahacktoberfest).
All of them are occupied by users but mostly nobody made PR.

So should I wait until the end of #hacktoberfest or may I ask them about theirs plans to finish it? how to do it so as not to seem rude?

What if other contributors would like to participate but they see that all busy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting together a PR may take time, especially if this is the first time someone contributes to this project (or to open source at all, for that matter!). I'd give a grace period of at least a week or two, but after that, you should reach out proactively. Not only is it not rude, but if you phrase your communication properly it will come off as encouraging, not nagging:

> Hey @JohnDoe, how are you doing?
>   You self-assigned this issue more than two weeks ago (on October 8th). I was just wondering how things are going with it, and whether you need any help.

Comment: In fact, in the end almost all responded and sent PR! So this helped. Thanks! :)